# Printing NSData using NSLog

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I print the contents of an NSData object using NSLog:

```
-(void) post:(NSString*) msg to:(NSString*) link{
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"message=%@", msg];
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: link]]; 
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    NSLog("%@", *returnData); //doesn't work

}
```

I would like to print the contents of *returnData...

Comment: isn't part of the problem here that you are using NSLog("") and not NSLog(@"").  (Aka you are passing a C string and not NSString?) (regardless of the formatting?)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", returnData);
```

The NSData will be logged in hex format.  I think that is probably what you are after.

If you want to turn it into a string and log the string, you first need to find out what character set was used.  **The default character set for HTTP is not UTF-8, it is ISO-8859-1**.  One way to do that is to examine the `Content-Type` header for the charset section.

Comment: This is the correct answer you can not assume content encoding of data! There is a reason for http headers, byte order marks etc, all text is not the same.

Comment: I think this is a better answer.

Comment: To inspect the hex data as a readable string, this usually works pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38225931/1054573 :)

Answer (score 85):

Convert NSData to NSString using

```
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and print NSString in NSLog like below

```
NSLog(@"%@",strData);
```

This answer is edited for JeremyP, as he does not know how to know content is of UTF-8, though it was not a discussion of this question.

You can get response header in following delegate method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSDictionary *dic = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
}
```

This dictionary will give you entire header info like below

```
<CFBasicHash 0x5a45e40 [0x24b2380]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x5d1bf60 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "X-Aspnet-Version"} = <CFString 0x5d21a60 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "2.0.50727"}
1 : <CFString 0x41a03a8 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Server"} = <CFString 0x5d272f0 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"}
2 : <CFString 0x41a0010 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Content-Length"} = <CFString 0x5d28630 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "385"}
6 : <CFString 0x419ff48 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Cache-Control"} = <CFString 0x5d29c70 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "private, max-age=0"}
10 : <CFString 0x5d1c640 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "X-Powered-By"} = <CFString 0x5d26f10 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "ASP.NET"}
11 : <CFString 0x41a0060 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Content-Type"} = <CFString 0x5d29c90 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
12 : <CFString 0x41a0088 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Date"} = <CFString 0x5d27610 [0x24b2380]>{contents = "Fri, 08 Jul 2011 15:23:10 GMT"}
}
```

Check charset="utf-8", you will get encoding from here.

Comment: if it works for you, can you mark it as answer, so others can view it as right answer?

Comment: it gives me this -> warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: you need to do NSLog(strData); what are you passing to NSLog?

Comment: How do you know the data is in UTF-8.

Comment: you can check in didReceiveResponse about content type Content-Encoding.

Comment: @jeremyP, please check my edited answer, it is specially for you.

Comment: @Jignesh: I down voted you because your answer assumes an HTTP message is UTF-8.  This is a false assumption.  The default encoding (acording to RFC 2616), if non is specified in the `Content-Type`, is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @JeremyP: Thanks for sharing knowledge. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Jignesh: If you edit the answer to remove the assumption and post a comment, I'll remove the down vote.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you must consider too:

```
NSLog(@"%@", *returnData); // this is wrong.

NSLog(@"%@", returnData); // this is correct.
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: you forgot to add @ in the NSLog function.

Answer (score 4):

I somewhat often want to see what the NSData actually represent. Usually it's some sort of text, which makes hex a bit inconvenient. Therefore I usually write this snippet in the JavaScript console in my web browser, works pretty fast and can be modified easily if some continued processing would be wanted.

1. Copy/paste the following script into your browser console (right click here -> Inspect element), hit enter

   ```
   (function nsDataHexToString() {
       var str = prompt("Paste the hex string here:", "ié. 48656c6c 6f207468 657265...")
       var chs = str.replace(/[^A-F0-9]/ig,"").split("")
       var res = ""
       var cnt = 2
       for (var i = 0; i+cnt-1<chs.length; i+=cnt) {
           var nr = ""
           for (var j=0; j<cnt; j++)
               nr += chs[i+j]
           nr = parseInt(nr, 16)
           res += String.fromCharCode(nr)
       }
       console.log(res)
       return res
   })()
   ```
2. Run your swift/obj-c code, put in a breakpoint and inspect your NSData object

   ```
   let sample = "Hello there"
   let data = sample.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   // Put breakpoint here, hover over "data", and press the eye/i
   ```
3. Copy the hex (something like `<48656c6c 6f207468 657265>`) and paste into the browser prompt
4. The console will then show a string: "Hello there"

Most recently, it was to inspect the output from `NSAttributedString.dataFromRange`, the rtfd was using a bit different encoding, but I got what I needed :) Also useful for some json conversion issues, etc.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thx @CoryImdieke! glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer if you need to have your data bytes as string

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520655/1344237